# TestNG - Running same class with multiple threads in parallel

Tags: multithreading, selenium, testng

Is there a way to run same class in parallel with multiple threads, like

```
<suite name="myTestSuite" verbose="1">
    <test name="myTest" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
        <classes>
            <class name="myPackage.Test" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I want to the class 'myPackage.Test' to be invoked in 5 parallel threads.I know that it works if I want to executed different classes in parallel, like

```
<suite name="myTestSuite" verbose="1">
    <test name="myTest" parallel="classes" thread-count="5">
        <classes>
            <class name="myPackage.Test1" />
            <class name="myPackage.Test2" />
            <class name="myPackage.Test3" />
            <class name="myPackage.Test4" />
            <class name="myPackage.Test5" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: What happens if you repeat <class name="....." /> 5 times?

Comment: What does "to run same class in parallel" mean? Do you want to run the same tests many times?

Comment: @Grasshopper - If I am repeating the class name 5 times, it is running only once.

Comment: @JulienHerr - Yes, I want to run the same test many times, but in parallel with many threads, like load testing

Answer (score 2):

As an alternate to the Factory pattern, you could create a `<test>` node for each time you want to run the class, then parallelize by `test`.  You'd also want to move your parallelization attributes to the `<suite>` node.  For example:

```
<suite name="mySuite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">

    <test name="myTest1">
        <classes>
            <class name="myPackage.Test" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <!-- Repeat the '<test>' node as many times as you wish to run the class -->

</suite>
```

You'll have to name each `<test>` uniquely, but this is decently simple way to run the same class many times and in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using a [`Factory`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories) to create 5 instances of your test class.

```
public class TestFactory {

  @Factory
  public Object[] createInstances() {
   Object[] result = new Object[5]; 
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      result[i] = new Test();
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

Then, you can use [`parallel="instances"`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parallel-tests).

```
<suite name="myTestSuite" verbose="1">
    <test name="myTest" parallel="instances" thread-count="5">
        <classes>
            <class name="myPackage.TestFactory"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```